# Htaccess rewrite rule from repertory load sub domain urls

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do something for 2 website. The main one is on **www.personal.com** then there is a wordpress blog hosted on another server could be loaded on **blog.personal.com**

I want to mask the urls as main site with **/blog/** architecture and load (with transparency) the same sub domain urls

Example : **www.personal.com/blog/my-first-article** will load *blog.personal.com/my-first-article* BUT with keeping this url in the browser (the url in browser will ne change) :

**www.personal.com/blog/my-first-article**

Last **difficulty**, the .htaccess file is used by others websites I host, then I do not want theses rules for others domain than personal.com The rule should be only for one domain name.

Does anyone know how to to this ?

Comment: You will need proxy functionality for this. Go read up on the [flag `[P]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p). _“The rule should be only for one domain name”_ – then prepend it with a `RewriteCond` that checks the requested host name.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read about the proxy flag [P] but wasn't sure if it was the right way.

Comment: This can't work if they are on two different servers... The two sites have to be on the same server. Then you modify the WordPress files to handle routing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the right thing was, in the Apache VHOST  configuration :

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.personal\.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
  RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.personal.com/$1 [P,QSA]

  ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.personal.com/
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.personal\.com/blog/ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+/)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|css|js)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.personal.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```